# Get the number of rows of the mysql table in this format 000.000.009 using Vuejs and Axios

Tags: php, html, mysql, vuejs2, axios

How to retrieve the number of data stored in the database and then display them on the screen in this form?
exemple: 000.000.959
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IWI9.jpg)

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$request = $data->request;

// Get All records
if($request == 1){
  $userNumbers = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
  $response = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userNumbers)){
    $response[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
```

This is my Vuejs Code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#myapp',
            data: {
              users: []
            },
            methods: {
                allUsersNumber(){
                  axios.get('api/app.php', {
                    request: 1
                  }).then(response => console.log(response));
                  console.log('Hello word')
                }
            },
          created: function(){
            this.allUsersNumber();
          }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, a MySQL problem, a HTML problem, or any JS related problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple concat would do the trick.

Use,

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("", "000.000.", numbers) AS numbers
FROM numbers;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xyfkQBiS)

Answer (score 0):

[Ergest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046021/1891677) will display `1000` as `000.000.1000`, which you probably do not want.

If you want `1000` to be displayed as `000.001.000` and `12345678900` as `12.345.678.900`, get the value from backend as number and parse it in JavaScript, with something like:

```js
function formatNumber(n) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumIntegerDigits: 9 }).format(n)
}
```

Demo:

```js
const formatNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 9
}).format;

[0, 1, 123456, 12345678900].map(formatNumber).map((n) => console.log(n));
```